# How do I force the use of LDPI images on an HDPI Android device?

Tags: android, drawable, resolution, hdpi

I have LDPI, MDPI, HDPI, and XHDPI drawables. I understand that Android selects the drawables that are appropriate for the device resolution, but I want to force an HDPI device to use LDPI drawables as an example of what NOT to do. I've tried referencing @drawable-ldpi/imagename, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help?

Comment: I should also add that I don't wish to remove the MDPI, HDPI, and XHDPI drawables from their respective directories.

Comment: then you can just add a suffix to the file, like "myimage_ldpi", and put it in the HDPI folder. I don't think there is a non-ugly-hack to achieve what you want otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just put the LDPI images in in the HDPI fold